# Parsing XML in java Malformedurlexception

Tags: java, xml, parsing, url, malformedurlexception

I am trying to parse an xml file but `Malformedurlexception` occurs. Do you have any idea why it is happening?

note: in first code segment there is a line as comment `system.out.println(requestXml)` it is working (the xml content is coming right as string) but i want to parse it but parse method is not working.

**Code**

```
String requestXml = "";

try {
    String argUrl = "http://192.168.1.25:3480/data_request?id=sdata&output_format=xml";

    URL url = new URL(argUrl);
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    // specify that we will send output and accept input
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);

    con.setConnectTimeout(20000);  // long timeout, but not infinite
    con.setReadTimeout(20000);

    con.setUseCaches(false);
    con.setDefaultUseCaches(false);

    // tell the web server what we are sending
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");

    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
    writer.write(requestXml);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    // reading the response
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());

    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    char[] cbuf = new char[2048];
    int num;

    while (-1 != (num = reader.read(cbuf))) {
        buf.append(cbuf, 0, num);
    }
    requestXml = buf.toString();
    xmlParser(requestXml);

    //System.out.println(requestXml);

} catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
return requestXml;
```

and xmlParser method is:

```
protected void xmlParser(String xmlToBeParsed) {

    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlToBeParsed);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("devices");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodes.item(i);

            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element element = (Element) node;
                System.out.println("Stock Symbol: " + getValue("device name", element));

            }
        }

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
    NodeList nodes = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
    Node node = (Node) nodes.item(0);
    return node.getNodeValue();
}
```

the log is:

> 04-30 11:55:21.299: W/System.err(826): java.net.MalformedURLException:
>   Protocol not found:  04-30 11:55:21.299:
>   W/System.err(826): 
>   04-30 11:55:21.299: W/System.err(826):  04-30 11:55:21.299:
>   W/System.err(826):  04-30
>   11:55:21.299: W/System.err(826):  04-30 11:55:21.299:
>   W/System.err(826):  04-30 11:55:21.299:
>   W/System.err(826):  04-30 11:55:21.299:
>   W/System.err(826):  04-30 11:55:21.299: W/System.err(826):
>    04-30
>   11:55:21.309: W/System.err(826):  04-30 11:55:21.309: W/System.err(826):  04-30
>   11:55:21.309: W/System.err(826):  04-30
>   11:55:21.309: W/System.err(826):  04-30 11:55:21.309: W/System.err(826):
>    04-30 11:55:21.309: W/System.err(826):  04-30
>   11:55:21.309: W/System.err(826):  04-30 11:55:21.309: W/System.err(826):  04-30 11:55:21.309:
>   W/System.err(826):  04-30 11:55:21.309: W/System.err(826):  04-30 11:55:21.309:
>   W/System.err(826): 
>   04-30 11:55:21.309: W/System.err(826):  04-30
>   11:55:21.309: W/System.err(826):  04-30 11:55:21.309:
>   W/System.err(826):    at java.net.URL.(URL.java:178) 04-30
>   11:55:21.309: W/System.err(826):  at java.net.URL.(URL.java:127)
>   04-30 11:55:21.309: W/System.err(826):    at
>   org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:115)
>   04-30 11:55:21.319: W/System.err(826):    at
>   javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:155)
>   04-30 11:55:21.319: W/System.err(826):    at
>   com.example.eos.SensorDataConnector.xmlParser(SensorDataConnector.java:93)
>   04-30 11:55:21.319: W/System.err(826):    at
>   com.example.eos.SensorDataConnector.getXMLData(SensorDataConnector.java:71)
>   04-30 11:55:21.319: W/System.err(826):    at
>   com.example.eos.EnergyOptimizer$5.onClick(EnergyOptimizer.java:148)
>   04-30 11:55:21.319: W/System.err(826):    at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) 04-30 11:55:21.319:
>   W/System.err(826):    at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355) 04-30
>   11:55:21.319: W/System.err(826):  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 04-30
>   11:55:21.319: W/System.err(826):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 04-30
>   11:55:21.319: W/System.err(826):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 04-30 11:55:21.319:
>   W/System.err(826):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 04-30
>   11:55:21.319: W/System.err(826):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-30
>   11:55:21.319: W/System.err(826):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 04-30 11:55:21.319:
>   W/System.err(826):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   04-30 11:55:21.319: W/System.err(826):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 04-30
>   11:55:21.329: W/System.err(826):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are using to parse the XML is [this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29):

```
public Document parse(String uri) throws SAXException, IOException
```

It basically expect an uri from which to fetch the content. This is not your case, because you already have queried the URL and parsed the contents. You are not supplying what the method expects.

I think you should be all right if you skip all the reading of the connection input stream and just do:

```
InputStream input = con.getInputStream();
xmlParser(input);
```

Note I have removed many lines. And then:

```
protected void xmlParser(InputStream input)
{

    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(input);
```

Comment: but you used dbuilder? i mean which part is wrong in my code. I didn't understand what is your suggestion? can you give more detail in code?

Comment: @abidinberkay I have edited my answer so, hopefully it will be easier to understand.

Comment: thanks for the help but how can i get them one by one and write them to the console (i know im a beginner) i mean what to do after doc.

Comment: @abidinberkay Try it the same way you have tried it today. If you still encounter further problems - this will be an issue with the parsing, subject to another question. I think you should be fine...